# How to add icon near text in TextArea in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I have text area with text (some help tip) and I want to add info icon before text in order it looks like:

```
icon -----
----------
----------
-----.

*icon: help icon
*---: help text
```

If it is impossible to add icon to TextArea, maybe there're any other solutions on how to do it (in a label?)?

Comment: Why do you want an icon in a TextArea? TextArea is used for users to enter text. It's not used to show text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an icon to the TextArea. You can show an icon on top of a TextArea in a specified location (by adding both icon and TextArea to a div and using relative positioning), but then it will obscure the text under it as users type it in.

Comment: I enhance current UI and I found text area where should be an icon at the beginning (it wasn't my decision). So if it is impossible to make it good looking, is it possible to make it somehow else? I mean an area with the text that begins with an icon?

Comment: If this is not a user input, you can simply use a Label instead of TextArea. Then you can put an icon before it.

Answer (score -1):

You only need CSS directives :

```
.yourClass {
     background-image : url('yourImage.png');
     background-repeat : no-repeat;
     padding-left : 30px; 
}
```

.yourClass is the CSS class to set on your TextArea.

30px corresponds to the image width to avoid the text to be positioned on it.