# Insert ICON/PNG inside TextArea

Tags: java, gwt

Without resorting to wrapping a GWT `TextArea` in a separate DIV, how to add a search icon/magnifier icon inside the text area?

Comment: Not possible. In HTML, you cannot put an image into a `<textarea>` tag. You can still try to cheat with some CSS.

Comment: where do you want the icon, in a corner, in the center...? do you want to interact with that icon, click ...?

Comment: You can always make a custom widget that consists of a `TextArea` and a `Button` with the image that floats over it in some corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Not possible.`Text area` is not a normal `Widget`.

GWT's TextArea maps directly to a `HTML` `TextArea` thats why you can only set text to it. The only thing you can do ist create a `Grid/VerticalPanel/HorizontalPanel` and put in each cell a separate TextArea.

[Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/rN1pgrj_IGc)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436863/how-to-add-icon-near-text-in-textarea-in-gwt)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Composite` wrapping a `FlowPanel`, put a text area and an image inside, then in CSS position the icon absolutely so it's over the text field.